# .NET Cannot perform this operation while dispatcher processing is suspended

Tags: .net, wpf

I have the following method in a base class that implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
protected virtual void RaisePropertyChangedEventSynchronous(string propertyName)
{                    
    try
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            Delegate[] delegates = this.PropertyChanged.GetInvocationList();
            foreach (PropertyChangedEventHandler handler in delegates)
            {                      
                try
                {
                    DispatcherObject dispatcherInvoker = handler.Target 
                        as DispatcherObject;
                    if (dispatcherInvoker != null)
                    {                                
                        dispatcherInvoker.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
                            new Action(delegate
                        {
                            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                        }));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {                     
                    ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, 
                        ExceptionHandlingPolicyNames.LogPolicy);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, ExceptionHandlingPolicyNames.LogPolicy);
    }
}
```

On occasion, I would get the following exception logged to file:

Type : System.InvalidOperationException, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Message : Cannot perform this operation while dispatcher processing is suspended.
Source : WindowsBase
Help link : 
Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite : Void PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
Stack Trace :    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Wait(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method)
   at OCC600.Infrastructure.Dictionary.BusinessEntities.Observable.RaisePropertyChangedEventSynchronous(String propertyName)

If I use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to update the UI, I do not get these exceptions. But I have found out that performing updates using BeginInvoke is not reliable as sometimes these changes are not reflected on the user interface.

How do I solve this one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I presume you're on a background thread and are trying to raise your PropertyChanged event on the UI thread. I think WPF handles the thread change for you; you shouldn't have to do this.

Here's some code I wrote. XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
  </Grid>
```

C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
  public MainWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = new Backgrounder();
  }

  class Backgrounder : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    int value = 0;
    public Backgrounder() {
      ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => {
        while (true) {
          this.value++;
          Notify("Value");
          Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }
      });
    }

    public int Value { get { return this.value; } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void Notify(string property) {
      PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null) { 
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property)); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you.  This should simply things alot.  To refresh collections, however, I have to do a dispatcher.invoke on the CollectionView.Refresh() method otherwise an exception is thrown.

Comment: For that, you should use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke. There is no other solution, as you need to be on the dispatcher thread and there is no reliable way to tell when the dispatcher is suspended.

Comment: Thanks.  Checked again and I am using BeginInvoke to refresh collections.